# Opening a document from Document Set vs. using direct Link

Tags: 2010, document, document-set, url

I have some documents stored in a document Set.

I noticed that opening the file by clicking on it in the document set produces a different behavior than taking this exact same link and putting it on a browser.

using IE, when clicking on the document, I get this dialog box:
[image]

but when I copy the shortcut and use it directly in the browser, i get this dialog box:

[image]

same thing in Firefox:

when clicking on the document, I get this dialog box:
[image]

but when I copy the shortcut and use it directly in the browser, i get this dialog box:
[image]

What can I do in order to always open the document in a way similar to clicking on its name in the document set?

I am using SP 2010 enterprise edition. site collection is using publishing template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when clicking a link in a document library, there is an onclick event in the

> ```
> > <a href onclick="return
> > DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3','0','SharePoint.OpenDocuments','','','','1','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff','','')">
> ```

This is what causes the document to open in edit mode rather than just download it.